# How to monitor "mouse leave" event?

Tags: wpf, mouseevent

On my window, there is a textbox, a combobox and a TextBlock.

Now I click the textbox to focus on it.

I want to monitor the event: when click other controls (the combobox, the TextBlock, even the empty area on the window) besides this textbox.

Are there any events that can handle it directly? Rather than binding mouseevent for each control.

Comment: [Routed Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#what-is-a-routed-event)

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the tunneling `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` of the parent window:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Source != theTextBox)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Click detected outside the TextBox!");
        }
    };
}
```